# Does Helidon have a web-based project creation tool?

Tags: helidon

Am I misremembering Helidon having a web-based project creation tool similar to the tool spring initializr? I know of the Helidon CLI that provides similar functionality.

Some generic searches like Helidon initializer or starter do not return relevant results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It's available at the following URL: https://helidon.io/starter.